# How to close a JOptionPane message box when pressing the x button?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I used a JOptionPane showMessageDiaglog to display a message with options, but whenever I decide to back off and click the red X button. It still performs an action as if I pressed the first option. How do I make it close on exit?

here's how I wrote it:

```
int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(g, "?", "Check", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, l, l[0]);
```

Comment: Are you testing for `n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am using n to get an integer to use it later like if n = 0 do sth if n = 1 do sth else

Comment: So, frame the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) *"Returns:
an integer indicating the option chosen by the user, or CLOSED_OPTION if the user closed the dialog"* - So you should be checking to see if `n != JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION`, but the concept is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just simple.

```
//First of all put the options dialog code like this.
int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this, "?", "Check", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,null,null);
//Now grab the value of n into switch case like this.
switch(n)
{
    case 0:
        //Yes
    break;
    case 1:
        //No
    break;
    case 2:
        //Cancel
    break;
    case -1:
        //User pressed 'X' button on the options dialog.If you want to exit app here.
        System.exit(0);
    break;
}
```

Here is a tip.

**If you want to check the return value of any message dialog just get the return value and print it on the console or just show another message box with the return value in it.So you can understand easily,what happens when user press what button in the message dialog.**

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks :D I will try it. But it looks like it will work

Comment: You should consider using `YES_OPTION`, `NO_OPTION` and `CLOSE_OPTION` instead of numeric values, as the constants could change

Comment: Yes may be after a new Java update(but not so rapidly).It is just an easy work around.